# Wait for a CompletableFuture to be complete, then return a different value?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I have a `CompletableFuture<Void>` that calls an asynchronous method whose return type I can't change, or anything about it.

I want to wait for this method to be complete (I manually complete it), and then return a String value, how would I do this?

```
public String getServer(Player p) {
    FutureServer f = new FutureServer(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        sendUTF(p, "GetServer");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000); //so the future doesnt complete itself
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }), p.getUniqueId().toString());
    serverSet.add(f);
    String server = "";

    //server isn't final so I can't use it in the lambda
    f.getFutureVoid().whenComplete(v -> server = f.getServer()); 

    return server;
}

public class FutureServer {

    private CompletableFuture<Void> futureVoid;
    private String s;
    private String uuid;

    public FutureServer(CompletableFuture<Void> futureVoid, String uuid) {
        this.futureVoid = futureVoid;
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Void> getFutureVoid() {
        return futureVoid;
    }

    public boolean hasServer() {
        return s != null;
    }

    public void setServer(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public String getServer() {
        return s;
    }
}
```

I want to set string to equal `FutureServer#getServer()` (own method), but I need to wait until the `CompletableFuture<Void>` is completed. What do I do?

This is the method that gets called async and is unchangeable... the method I use that calls this other method asynchronously is `sendUTF()`.

```
@Override
public void onPluginMessageReceived(String s, Player p, byte[] bytes) {
    if (!s.equals("BungeeCord")) return;

    ByteArrayDataInput in = ByteStreams.newDataInput(bytes);
    String subChannel = in.readUTF();

    switch(subChannel) {
        case "GetServer":
            String server = in.readUTF();
            serverSet.stream().filter(f -> f.getUuid().equals(p.getUniqueId().toString())).findFirst().ifPresent(f -> {
                f.setServer(server); //getting the string I need and placing it into this object
                f.getFutureVoid().complete(null); //completing the void future manually
            });
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: So using `CompletableFuture<Void>` is a requirement?

Comment: Anyway, if your `getServer()` method has to return a `String`, then whatever it does has to be non-asynchronous. Even if the things it do is asynchronous, it has to wait for the final result before this method can return the correct value, so it will have to wait (calling thread will be blocked). The correct way is to make this method return some sort of `Future`.

Comment: I know that, Im fine with making the main thread wait, I just want to know how to get the value

Comment: If the calling thread is expected to block while the result is retrieved, then it would be much simpler to do all these non-asynchronously. Asynchronous approach is only meaningful only if you need to do something but could not afford to wait for results, such that you want to be notified when the result is available and you would go back to retrieve the result.

Comment: Read the post, its done async and I cant change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
final AtomicReference<String> server = new AtomicReference<>("");

f.getFutureVoid().whenComplete(v -> server.set(f.getServer())).get(/* maybe add a timeout */); 

return server.get();
```

Comment: Ill try that, any down sides to using this approach?

Comment: The thread that's calling getServer() will block until the future completes -- but I think you expect that?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is simply to `join()` on that future, either with:

```
public String getServer(Player p) {
    FutureServer f = new FutureServer(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        sendUTF(p, "GetServer");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000); //so the future doesnt complete itself
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }), p.getUniqueId().toString());
    serverSet.add(f);

    return f.getFutureVoid().thenApply(v -> f.getServer()).join(); 
}
```

which can easily be transformed to return a `CompletableFuture<String>` instead by removing the `.join()`, or also:

```
public String getServer(Player p) {
    FutureServer f = new FutureServer(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        sendUTF(p, "GetServer");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000); //so the future doesnt complete itself
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }), p.getUniqueId().toString());
    serverSet.add(f);

    f.getFutureVoid().join();
    return f.getServer();
}
```